# VideoView does not fill layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview

I made a videoview and at the bottom of the screen there is another relative layout. In simulator it shows ok how it should be, but when i launch the app it doesnt.

[Image from emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csiNI.png)

Now when i launch it shows me such layout

[Layout when launching app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPZlA.png)

Am i doing something wrong in the code behind?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonsLayout" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonsLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#404040"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_accept_video"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/accept" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_reject_video"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/reject" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the videoview fill the layout but its the video u played that dosen't

Comment: ok and how to fix it ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding the following attributes in `VideoView`.

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Check [this](http://blog.kasenlam.com/2012/02/android-how-to-stretch-video-to-fill.html) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<VideoView android:id="@+id/videoViewRelative"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</VideoView>
```

Hope this will help you